# Completions for bash 4 never finish loading

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew

I've installed bash 4 and bash-completions@2 with Homebrew following all kinds of guides I found online. However, when I open a new terminal it just hangs. By placing some `echo`s in my `.bash_profile` it seems to be hanging on loading the completions.

My `.bash_profile`:

```
# Import all files
for DOTFILE in ~/.{aliases,env,functions,path,prompt,extra}
do
    [ -r "$DOTFILE" ] && [ -f "$DOTFILE" ] && source "$DOTFILE"
done

unset DOTFILE;

echo $BASH_VERSION
printf "Loading bash completions..."
if [ -f /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi
printf "done!"

if [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh" ]; then
    GIT_PROMPT_THEME=Default
    source "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh"
fi
```

(the `DOTFILE` stuff is loading my [dotfiles](https://github.com/fiskeben/dotfiles))

When I open a new terminal with the above `.bash_profile` I get this output:

```
Last login: Fri Jun 23 10:43:12 on ttys001
4.4.12(1)-release
Loading bash completions...
```

Running `brew doctor` doesn't say anything about bash completions.

What can I do to get this working?

**UPDATE**
There were a bunch of `rustc` processes taking up a lot of CPU. Most likely related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was with `rustc`. Upgrading the package with `brew upgrade rust` fixed it.

My current Rust version is now 1.18.0.